# Google's reCAPTCHA broken when using Selenium

Tags: selenium, recaptcha

I'm trying to automate a process where one page can only be accessed after filling a reCAPTCHA (asking to identify images).

I'm not interested in solving the captcha automatically as it is enough for me to complete the captcha manually and let the other tasks be automated; the only problem is that the captcha widget is broken and exhibits a weird bug in the Firefox window opened by Selenium (while it works fine with my normal Firefox instances) making me unable to complete it, even manually.

The bug: every time I try to select an image it fades out and a new one pops up, taking its place. I'm not able to keep any images selected and can't verify the captcha.

What could cause this behaviour? The two Firefox instances appear identical (same user agent as well) but there must be something different for this to happen. How can I debug this?

Comment: if you are are testing on behalf of the site developer try using test keys to stop the capture triggering: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq

Answer (score 0):

Fading out of images is one of the expected behaviour of reCAPTCHA. If an image fades out when clicked on it, other will take place of it. This will happen until you have clicked on all the images which reCAPTCHA has asked you to select. Once you have completed clicking on all the images then you can click on checkbox available on reCAPTCHA popup, you will get through reCAPTCHA. Also you can refer this reCAPTCHA FAQ page for more details -> https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq

Hope this helps.